# Express multer send array images - How to right config to pass an array and not a single file

Tags: express, multer

Hey everone I am new to this type of configuration with express and I am not 100% sure if the problem is coming from the backend or frontend. So I am trying to upload an array of images so this was done

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    const fileExt = path.extname(file.originalname);
    const fileName = uuidv4() + fileExt; 
    cb(null, fileName);
  }
});

app.post('/upload', upload.array('arrayImages',3), (req, res) => {
    res.json({ imageName: req.arrayImages });
  });
```

Also just to clarify, on this 2 lines of code above, I also tried to print just the **req.body**, **req.files** and **req**, but I get the same effect.

That's how the frontend function looks like:

```
    async uploadImages(arrayImages) {
      console.log(arrayImages);
      const formData = new FormData();
      //formData.append('arrayImages', arrayImages[0]); I used this to test with one image
      for (const file of arrayImages) {
        formData.append('arrayImages', file);
      }
      
    fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_IP_SERVER}upload`, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
          alert('Upload failed');
      });
    }
```

I realized that when trying to pass just one image it works, that means like in the backend I change to:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('arrayImages'), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ imageName: req.file.filename });
});
```

And in the frontend I use the commented code instead of passing the whole array.Just like that I got the file uploaded. So means it should be an issue with the way the array is pass, not sure if I am doing it correctly or I am just missing an extra configuration. Also in the backend with the arrays I got the error: 'Converting circular to JSON'

The arrayImages variable looks like this in structure:

[image]

So any type of advice or help will be very welcome. Thank you in advance